# parse the child tags with a specific matching string in xml using python

Tags: python, xml

i want parse the xml string having tag Topics as parent tag and Topic1,Topic2 as child tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SignificantDevelopments Major="3" Minor="0" Revision="1" xmlns="urn:reuterscompanycontent:significantdevelopments03"><Topics><Topic1 Code="254">Regulatory / Company Investigation</Topic1><Topic2 Code="207">Mergers &amp; Acquisitions</Topic2><ParentTopic1 Code="6">Litigation / Regulatory</ParentTopic1><ParentTopic2 Code="4">Ownership / Control</ParentTopic2></Topics></SignificantDevelopments>
```

I just want to parse this xml so that i can get the attribute value of every Topic tag, I just want it to be in for loop.

i have tried with the following code:

```
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
    tree = ET.ElementTree(file='sample.xml')

    #get the root element
    root = tree.getroot()
    namespace = {'xmlns': 'urn:reuterscompanycontent:significantdevelopments03'}

    for devs in root.findall('xmlns:Topics' ,namespace):
        for child_tags in devs.findall('xmlns:./', namespace):
            print 'child: ', child_tags.tag
```

I just want to add some wild card like Topic/d in second last line so that i can parse every tag matching Topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that the `tag` property starts with the namespace plus the prefix `Topic`, for instance

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SignificantDevelopments Major="3" Minor="0" Revision="1" xmlns="urn:reuterscompanycontent:significantdevelopments03"><Topics><Topic1 Code="254">Regulatory / Company Investigation</Topic1><Topic2 Code="207">Mergers &amp; Acquisitions</Topic2><ParentTopic1 Code="6">Litigation / Regulatory</ParentTopic1><ParentTopic2 Code="4">Ownership / Control</ParentTopic2></Topics></SignificantDevelopments>')
topics = [el for el in root.findall('*/*') if el.tag.startswith('{urn:reuterscompanycontent:significantdevelopments03}Topic')]
for topic in topics:
    print (topic.text)
```

or shorter as

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SignificantDevelopments Major="3" Minor="0" Revision="1" xmlns="urn:reuterscompanycontent:significantdevelopments03"><Topics><Topic1 Code="254">Regulatory / Company Investigation</Topic1><Topic2 Code="207">Mergers &amp; Acquisitions</Topic2><ParentTopic1 Code="6">Litigation / Regulatory</ParentTopic1><ParentTopic2 Code="4">Ownership / Control</ParentTopic2></Topics></SignificantDevelopments>')

for topic in [el for el in root.findall('*/*') if el.tag.startswith('{urn:reuterscompanycontent:significantdevelopments03}Topic')]:
    print (topic.text)
```

Or put the check into an `if` statement inside of your `for` statements.

Comment: thankyou so much, it worked!! :) can u please suggest me some kind of sources where i can build my python skills.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info has a lost list of links to tutorials, courses and articles.

Comment: if i need to use like startswith('xmlns:Topic', namespace)] where namespace will be equal to  {urn:reuterscompanycontent:significantdevelopments03}